# bash pipe variable in another command

Tags: bash, openssl

I want to execute open-ssl to encrypt many times a file with a wordlist. Everytime I am using:

```
  openssl enc -e -rc4 -in plain -out cipher
  enter rc4 encryption password:
```

and what I want to do is

```
  echo "differentpasswordeverytime" | openssl enc -e -rc4 -in plain -out cipher
```

I have done the while loop but I cant find a way to parse this into openssl. This should be through STDIN of openssl ?

I found 2 other posts regarding stdin and parsing input but these didnt work.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from `man openssl` (near the end):

> #### PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS
>
> Several commands accept password arguments, typically using `-passin` and `-passout` for input and output passwords respectively. These allow the password to be obtained from a variety of sources. Both of these options take a single argument whose format is described below. If no password argument is given and a password is required then the user is prompted to enter one: this will typically be read from the current terminal with echoing turned off.

That's followed by a list of possible ways of acquiring the password. I would think that the one you want is `stdin`, although it might well work out better to use the option for an environment variable. (You'll need to `export` the variable for that to work.)

I suggest you read the description carefully, taking account of the security implications. You should also read the manpage for the subcommand you are using (`enc`), or at least read through the summary provided if you specify an option it does not understand.

(In `enc`, the actual option specified is neither `-passin` nor `-passout` but rather `-pass`.)

Comment: Thanks for your response rici, however it looks I cant use -passin with the rc4 (?) and provide the password through command line

Comment: @user3124171: A little more manpage reading would have revealed the answer, but I edited mine anyway: you need to use `-pass`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pipe a variable into a command, you should use `echo` but be careful as implementations can vary, and multi-line variables can sometimes be collapsed into a single line.
For me in bash
`echo "$variable" | command`
worked, and kept multi-line strings.

If you want internal `/n` and other escaped characters to be evaluated into newlines you should pass the `-e` flag like so:

`echo -e "$variable" | command`